# Is there an equivalent to Grbl for Excellon PCB drilling?

Tags: mechanical

For CNC milling we have code such as Grbl Controller in the PC, and Grbl itself in an Arduino, and these handle the appropriate G-code files. Is there an equivalent package to handle Excellon files and drive a 3-axis drilling machine?

Comment: Most PCB software will export to Gerber-files. There is already software that does pcb milling, including hole-drilling. I'm not into this stuff, but a google search for "gerber cnc" might give you better results.

Comment: Thanks Gerben. I will look into the pcb milling packages. If there is one that will talk to Grbl *and* if it has a sub-menu that will handle a drill file as a separate operation, then that could be the easiest way to go.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no existing Arduino library to parse [Excellon format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excellon_format) drill files in order to control a drilling machine. Looking at the [specification](http://web.archive.org/web/20071030075236/http://www.excellon.com/manuals/program.htm) it looks to be very similar to G Code, and some brief googling shows that there are various utilities for converting it to G Code that could be run from something like grbl.

Comment: Thanks Jake. See my comment to Gerben. If there isn't a direct pcb package, then yes, I guess I'll have to do an Excellon --> Gcode then through say, Grbl Controller --> Grbl.